# How to redirect from one domain to another in Express?

Tags: javascript, express

To be precise, my website is currently being redirected to appID-appspot.com

How can I force a redirect to my custom domain ?

That is, when gets "appID-appspot.com", redirect to "custom domain".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use regular expression route matching of express.**

```
app.get(/appID-appspot.com/, function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('custom_domain');
}
```

**`/appID-appspot.com/`**

matches the `url` and redirects to customdomain, if the URL contains that part.

Add the above to top of the routes so that it gets redirected first.

Comment: I am sure this is the correct answer, but sadly it did not help in my case, it seems the redirected is operated before my app code is even called.

Comment: do one thing, to test this code, `app.get(/appID-appspot.com/, function (req, res) {
  res.send('custom_domain');
}` and check when it got called

Comment: How can I check when it got called ?

Comment: `res.send('test message');` this line prints the message `test message` as a response

Comment: Sadly, nothing prints.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com');`

Full example:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect(301, 'custom domain');
});
```